# Data Studio (Golang RE2): how to capitalize first letter of each word in string

Tags: looker-studio, re2

I am connecting directly to a data source (Google Analytics) in Data Studio. I am using the field "Page Title" which is a text field.

I wish to add a **calculated field** which capitalizes the first letter of each word in the string of the field "Page Title".

Example:

| Current state | Desired output |
| --- | --- |
| What to expect from the authorities in 2021 | What To Expect From The Authorities In 2021 |
| Sustainability – An emerging theme | Sustainability – An Emerging Theme |
| Helping UK businesses make confident decisions | Helping UK Businesses Make Confident Decisions |

The first part is easy. I can find the first letter of each word that starts with a lowercase by using

```
(\b[a-z])
```

In old PHP I could use the token **\u** to replace with capital letters

```
\u$1
```

BUT when I use this in Google Data Studio like this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page Title,"(\b[a-z])","\u$1")
```

I get an error

```
Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \u must be followed by 4 hex digits but saw: \u).
```

From what I have researched, it seems that "\u" is not supported in RE2. But I have searched for 4.5hours and I can not find what to use to replace my match with capital letters.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\U...\E` is not supported by Data Studio's flavour of regex, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).